# Package:astrolog isn't available on Ubuntu repository?

Tags: apt, package-management, repository

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Astrology says: `astrolog` is available on Ubuntu repository:
[image]

But it is not located/available:

```
$ sudo apt-get install astrolog
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package astrolog
```

Also I can't find `astrolog` from Ubuntu repository:

- Searched at : [Ubuntu Packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=astrolog&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all)
- Searched at : [Ubuntu Updates](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package_metas/list?name=astrolog)
- Searched at : [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=astrolog)

So, Why it is not available ?

Comment: That wiki is talking about Astrolog in Ubuntu 6.06 (Dapper) (see reference link). Astrolog disappeared from the Ubuntu repos in 9.04 (Jaunty).

Comment: what is your ubuntu version?

Comment: @user308564 14.04 LTS

Comment: @muru Ok I visited. It is needed to update wiki.

Comment: there was an app called `meitreya` something like this for astrology.